# How to change the yiibooster yiibootsrap fixed container width

Tags: yii

Im using yiibooster with yiibootsrap in the yii framework. I dont want the site to be responsive so i set responsive to false. The problem is the default container width is too small, 940px. I want to change this to 1045px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `width` set in `protected/extensions/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css` here:

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 940px;
}
```

Alternatively, this is what I'm currently doing, you can override the CSS in your layout. In my `protected/views/layouts/main.php` I've added this style to the container `div` like this:

```
<div class="container" id="page" style="width:99%;">
```

Hope one of those options is useful to you...

Comment: **style="width:99%;"** - this one rocks! That's the easiest, most convenient and most effective way I've seen so far! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is in \protected\extensions\bootstrap\assets\bootstrap\css\bootstrap.no-responsive.css

If you look at the css carefully, you will find several places where the 940px is hard coded in the css. This is how you get the 940px.

You can edit this, but I would highly discourage doing so for 2 reasons. First it is highly discourage to hack the standard code. It is better to override it with your theme css. Second, there are other css elements that are tied to the 940px. Changing the 940px in the container css may break other css. To overcome this problem, open up the responsive css, i.e. \protected\extensions\bootstrap\assets\bootstrap\css\bootstrap.css

Search for the word @media

Keep on searching until you find 
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

what ever enclosed within the braces are the css elements that tied up to the container size. Copy them and place them at the end of your non-responsive file (or better in your theme css).

Thanks